# Wilcoxon rank test where sample sizes are very different

Tags: sample-size, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am undertaking a Wilcoxon rank test between two samples - say A and B. The number of observations in B is about 10 times the number of observations in A (1000 vs 100). Does this discrepancy in sample sizes impact the result's validity?

Comment: As an aside, a sample of 1,000 adults is likely to have some heterogeneity in terms of their survival: disability, personal history of disease, or prior treatment. You could fit a multivariate Cox model, or you can consider a matched cohort (case-cohort design) study, matching the 1,000 to the 100 to obtain a comparable sample. But without more information, this is not advised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, as long as a Wilcoxon rank test is appropriate in the first place.

The long answer is that a very different group size affects the power: you will typically have a lot more power with 550 vs. 550 observations than with 100 vs. 1000. If the analysis happens to be underpowered for the kind of effect sizes on one reasonably expect, then this makes it more likely that any apparent findings are false positive and a failure to reject the null hypothesis of no difference between groups is more likely to be a false negative.
Additionally, if the numbers were much smaller, then I might start to worry about the discreteness of the distribution of the test statistic etc., but with numbers like 100 vs. 1000 that is really not a concern (unless a lot of observations have the excact same outcome).